Cargo- domain transfer from Go Daddy has not transferred
I have transferred a domain to Cargo from Go Daddy, following Cargo's instructions to change the Name Servers on Go Daddy. After 5 days it still has not transferred the domain even though all of the correct steps have been followed. How do I fix this issue?
Changing the Name Servers to:
ns1.cargo.site
ns2.cargo.site
Still have the "This domain needs to be configured for use on Cargo" after 5 days.
